# Google auto complete API sometime returning wrong geocode

Tags: google-maps

I am using google auto complete API to search address. Some time after selecting the address it returns wrong latitude and longitude. Then I tried second time its working fine. What could be the cause for this?

The address tried: 21 King Street West, Toronto, ON, Canada

First time the Geo-code coming as below

40.7917804,-74.14482129999999 - wrong (USA Address)

Second time I am getting correct Geo-code

43.64877740000001,-79.37871480000001

```
 var address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(id)),{ types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: { country: 'ca' } });
        address.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            var place = address.getPlace();
            place = results[0];
            $j('#' + txtboxid).attr({
                 'data-lat': place.geometry.location.lat(),
                 'data-lon': place.geometry.location.lng()
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you post code sample that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: var address = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(id)),{ types: ['geocode'], componentRestrictions: { country: 'ca' } });
            address.addListener('place_changed', function () {
                var place = address.getPlace();
   place = results[0];
                $j('#' + txtboxid).attr({
                     'data-lat': place.geometry.location.lat(),
                     'data-lon': place.geometry.location.lng()
                });
            });

Comment: Can you also grab corresponding place IDs? I wonder what place ID you get first time?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type to address which is a precise location for premises: `types: ['address']`

Comment: I think this should be a comment instead